# Why do I add a [1] after i split the string?

Tags: c#, arrays

I've commented on the line where I am having issues, I do not fully understand why it has to be `[1]`, why can't it be `[0]`, `[2]` etc. I know that `[0]` switches the position of the first and last name but I don't understand why.

This is what the lines looks like in the textfile.

> Jonny:Cage
>   Sarah:Johnsson
>   Bob:Joe

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "Name list|*.txt";
    try
    {
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string[] nameList = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);
            foreach (string line in nameList)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

                string lastName = line.Split(':')[1]; //This is what I dont understand

                lvi.SubItems.Add(lastName);
                lvNames.Items.Add(lvi);

                string firstname = "";
                IP = line.Replace(lastName, "").Replace(":", "");
                lvi.Text = firstname;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: After you split `Jonny:Cage`, you have an array of two strings, `Jonny` and `Cage`. The first one is accessed via Index 0 and the second one with Index 1.

Comment: `Split` returns the array, you're asking for the 2nd item in that array to be returned as a `String`.  That will throw an error if there is no semicolon.

Comment: As mentioned from previous comments `Split` returns an array which can be accessed via an index. `[0]` is the first element (e.g. `Jonny`) while `[1]` corresponds the second element (`Cage`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the first line in your file `Jonny:Cage`. If you feed this text to the split method you will get an array with two values `Jonny`, `Cage`. In C# you address values in the array with 0 based index so if you use `0` you will access `Jonny` for `1` it is `Cage` any other value will result in an error as there are only two items in that array. And you want the last name so the `Cage` that is the second item in the array so you need to use `1`.

Comment: Oh, that was simple! Thank you so much for explaining!

Comment: @JonnyKhanas Not to be a bother, but you could have figured that out yourself if you had actually looked up each function you're calling in your code.

Comment: Yeah but this way went faster, and it was alot easier, why make my life harder even if its harder by the tiniest bit when I dont have too.

Answer (score 0):

The Split method takes a string and finds each part of the string when splitting it by a seperator character:

```
string s = "I am a sample string!I am the second part";
// Let's create an array 
string[] parts = s.Split('!'); // We split s into parts seperated by a '!'
// parts looks like this: ["I am a sample string", "I am the second part"] 
// The '!' is not part of it as it is the seperator.
// parts has the length of 2 -> two strings in an array of strings.
// Arrays have indexes of each element, starting with 0, not 1!
// So accessing the second element in parts is:
Console.WriteLine(parts[1]);
// Your frind just put the call of the second element right behind returning the array:
line.Split(':')[1]
// Split gives us the array and we take its second element -> the last name
```

Comment: While you're right, it's still not a direct answer to OP's question.